# shell : Number of string occurrences in a column using grep

Tags: bash, shell

My data file is:

```
name,age,favourite_person
Adam,19,Helen Keller
Alex,18,Joe Biden
Kyle,18,George Washington
Mary,20,Marie Curie
Jade,16,Marie Kondo
```

I want to find number of times "Marie" occurred in the column 'favourite_person' (column 3). My code right now is  `grep -R "Marie" file | wc -l` but this checks for the word "Marie" in the entire file. I only want it to check among the favourite_person column. What should I add in this case?

Comment: `awk` is more appropriate.

Comment: Or perhaps `cut`, e.g. ` grep -c "Marie" <(cut -d, -f3 file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk as follows:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } {if ($3 ~ "Marie") { count++ }} END { print count }' file
```

1. `BEGIN { FS = "," }` sets `,` as the field separator,
2. `{ if ... }` part reads like "if the third field matches "Marie", then increment variable `count`",
3. `END { print count }` prints `count` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` as well as `grep`:

`cut -d "," -f3 file | grep Marie | wc -l`

`-d` means delimeter, and `-f3` takes the third column only

`grep Marie` checks if Marie is in the third column, and `wc -l` counts the occurences

Comment: This one returns 9 less count compared to the awk method, I wonder why?